# What does pseudo pre-image of a hash function mean?

Tags: hash, terminology

So finding a pre-image means given the hash value, one tries to find a message that gives this value using the function's standard IV. What about pseudo-preimage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pseudo-preimage is the problem of finding $(IV, M)$ given $t$ such that $H(IV, M) = t\ $.